# how to use a Bool stored in an array of structs to use with isExpanded in a DisclosureGroup

Tags: ios, swiftui

hello I am fairly new to Swift/SwfitUI and StackOverflow. I have ran into a problem that I can't solve. I have been looking for the past couple of days on how to resolve this little problem and hoping the community can help.

what I would like to achieve is having several DisclosureGroups being displayed, as many as there are users in the array and then the Bool property being used in each record storing the isExpanded state.

Code runs but I get this error

> Accessing State's value outside of being installed on a View. This will result in a constant Binding of the initial value and will not update.

```
struct User: Identifiable {
let id = UUID()
let name:String
@State var isReal: Bool
}

class UsersContainer : ObservableObject {
@Published var users = [User]()

func fetchFromServer() {
    self.users.append(User(name: "Ehren", isReal: false))
}

}


struct ContentView: View {

@ObservedObject var usersContainer = UsersContainer()

var body: some View {
    VStack{
        Button(action: {
            self.usersContainer.fetchFromServer()
        }){
            Text("Fetch From Server")
        }
        List(usersContainer.users, id: \.id){user in
            DisclosureGroup(
                isExpanded: user.$isReal,
                content: { Text(user.name) },
                label: { Text("Name is") }
            ) }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: No need of using “@State" in User struct, “@State" are meant to be used locally in structs that implements view protocol. In your case you have already marked User struct with “@published" in UsersContainer class, so as soon as any property for that struct changes a notification will be triggered to refresh all  views  that are using “@ObservedObject" wrapper.

Comment: When I take the @State away and the line of code like this: 
 DisclosureGroup(
                    isExpanded: user.isReal,
                    content: { Text(user.name) },
I get an error
 
"Cannot convert value of type 'Bool' to expected argument type 'Binding<Bool>'"

Comment: Are you trying to expand based on isReal property?

Comment: Yes. It’s only a small code snippet but want it to have the list with records of students etc that I can expand with more details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the working solution.

```
import SwiftUI

    struct User: Identifiable,Equatable {
        let id = UUID()
        let name:String
        var isReal: Bool
    }
    
    class UsersContainer : ObservableObject {
        @Published var users = [User]()
        var res:[Bool] = []
        
        func fetchFromServer() {
            self.users.append(User(name: "Ehren", isReal: false))
            self.users.append(User(name: "Ehren1", isReal: false))
            self.users.append(User(name: "Ehren2", isReal: false))
            self.users.append(User(name: "Ehren3", isReal: false))
            self.users.append(User(name: "Ehren4", isReal: false))
            self.users.append(User(name: "Ehren5", isReal: false))
            self.users.append(User(name: "Ehren6", isReal: false))
            self.objectWillChange.send()
        }
        
   
        func getRealUser() -> [Bool] {
            for user in users{
                res.append(user.isReal)
            }
            
            return res
        }
    }
    
    
    struct ContentView: View {
        
        @ObservedObject var usersContainer = UsersContainer()
        @State private var isExpanded : [Bool] = []
        
        
        var body: some View {
            VStack{
                Button(action: {
                    self.usersContainer.fetchFromServer()
                    isExpanded = self.usersContainer.getRealUser()
                    
                }){
                    Text("Fetch From Server")
                }
                
                if isExpanded.count > 0{
                    List{
                        ForEach(0..<usersContainer.users.count) { index in
                            DisclosureGroup(
                                isExpanded: $isExpanded[index] ,
                                content: { Text(usersContainer.users[index].name) },
                                label: { Text("Name is") }
                            )
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            
            Spacer()
        }
    }
```